# chain rule ordering

Tags: probability, conditional-probability, bayesian-network

suppose I want to compute the joint probability $P(X,Y,Z)$ with chain rule. Is it true that there will be $3!$ possible factorization ? or is there more ? I got 6 for this example:

1. $P(X|YZ)P(Y|Z)P(Z)$
2. $P(X|YZ)P(Z|Y)P(Y)$
3. $P(Y|XZ)P(X|Z)P(Z)$
4. $P(Y|XZ)P(Z|X)P(X)$
5. $P(Z|YX)P(Y|X)P(X)$
6. $P(Z|YX)P(X|Y)P(Y)$

My second question is that is the value of each line is equal to other lines or not ? meaning that the chain rule will give the same value regardless the ordering ? I am assuming DAG and in my thinking that they are not equal and I want someone to confirm.
Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> . Is it true that there will be 3! possible factorisations?

Obviously.

There are $3$ ways to factorise out one variable from three:$$\begin{align}\mathsf P(X,Y,Z)&=\mathsf P(X,Y\mid Z)~\mathsf P(Z)\\&=\mathsf P(X,Z\mid Y)~\mathsf P(Y)\\&=\mathsf P(Y,Z\mid X)~\mathsf P(X)\end{align}$$

Likewise for each of those way there are two ways to factorise out one variable from two:$$\begin{align}\mathsf P(X,Y\mid Z)&=\mathsf P(X\mid Y,Z)~\mathsf P(Y\mid Z)\\&=\mathsf P(Y\mid X,Z)~\mathsf P(X\mid Z)\end{align}$$

---

> I am assuming DAG and in my thinking that they are not equal

A Directed Acyclic Graph maps a particular factorisation.  The factorisations are distinct but equal, so too are their corresponding DAG.

You can tell them apart, but they are all factorisations of the same joint probability.

---

Also, you do not need to assume a particular DAG; they are visual representations of factorisations.

A Directed Acyclic Graph is a visual representation for a particular factorisation.  Every DAG *encodes* a particular factorisation of the joint probability for its nodes.  Likewise every factorisation for that joint probability *will have* its own graphical *representation*.

Consider these two different looking graphs.  $\def\P{\operatorname{\sf P}}\require{enclose}\def\circle#1{\enclose{circle}#1}$

$$\begin{align}\begin{matrix}\circle{A}&\to& \circle B\\&\searrow&\downarrow\\&&\circle C\end{matrix}\text{ encodes } \P(A,B,C)=\P(A)\P(B\mid A)\,\P(C\mid A,B)\\[0ex]\\\hline\\[1ex]\begin{matrix}\circle{A}&\to& \circle B\\&\nwarrow&\uparrow\\&&\circle C\end{matrix}\text{ encodes } \P(A,B,C)=\P(C)\P(A\mid C)\,\P(B\mid A,C)\end{align}$$

Since both are factorisations for the same joint probability measure (and hence the factorisations are equal), we say the DAG are *equivalent*.

Comment: But what if I am not assuming a DAG ? are the 6 factorsations equal ?

Comment: @Cav  They have equal valuations, by the definition of conditional probability.

Comment: Also, you do not need to assume a DAG.  They are visual representation of a factorisation; there are many ways to factorise the probabiity, each has its own DAG.  There are six possible for three events with no specified conditional independancies.

Answer (score -1):

I always thought of $P(A|B)P(B) = P(B|A)P(A)$ by thinking of such tree:

[image]

First, $A$ happens, with $P(A)$, and then $B$ happens with $P(B|A)$, yielding $P(A,B) = P(B|A)P(A)$.

But you can totally flip the tree to have first $B$ and then $A$, thus yielding $P(A,B) = P(A|B)P(B)$.

(Putting it all together you then get the famous Baye's rule).

If there are three variables, I think it is correct to think of 6 possible trees that will directly correspond to your 6 derivations and will have have equal values since they all match the probability of the three events happening.

I'm not sure if this answer your questions :-)

Comment: I am assuming DAG and in my thinking that they are not equal and I want someone to confirm

Comment: The reasoning is the same as above but with 6 trees instead of 2. Isn't it?